# Count frequency of specific list in a dictionary

Tags: python

Let's say I have a dictionary:

```
thisdict = {
  "1": ['Vanilla','Chocolate']
  "2": ['Vanilla']
  "7": ['Chocolate']
  "8": ['Chocolate','Vanilla']
}
```

(note: the keys are ID Numbers)

I want to see a frequency of how many times a specific list occurs, disregarding the order of the elements. So I would want my result to be:

```
['Chocolate','Vanilla'] = 2
['Chocolate'] = 1
['Vanilla'] = 1
```

How would I do this?

Right now I tried, with Chief being the name of the dictionary I want to find the frequency of the values of:

```
track = {}

for key,value in chief.items():
    if value not in track:
        track[value]=0
    else:
        track[value]+=1

print(track)
```

But lists are not hashable, so it does not work.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: you can convert to tuples which are hashable.

Comment: Or better convert them to sets, so that `set(['Chocolate', 'Vanilla']) == set(['Vanilla', 'Chocolate'])`

Comment: Except sets aren't hashable either...

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you want to count the value in a manner that order doesn't matter. You can convert to a set, but sets are not hashable, which makes that a little harder. You can use a [frozenset](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset), which is hashable and will allow `['Chocolate','Vanilla']` to count the same as `['Vanilla','Chocolate']`:

```
from collections import Counter

thisdict = {
  "1": ['Vanilla','Chocolate'],
  "2": ['Vanilla'],
  "7": ['Chocolate'],
  "8": ['Chocolate','Vanilla']
}

counts = Counter(map(frozenset, thisdict.values()))
```

`counts` will be a counter instance like:

```
Counter({frozenset({'Chocolate', 'Vanilla'}): 2,
     frozenset({'Vanilla'}): 1,
     frozenset({'Chocolate'}): 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

Since order is to be disregarded you can convert the lists to `frozenset`s so that you can use `collections.Counter` to count the frequencies of each set of values:

```
from collections import Counter

for combination, count in Counter(map(frozenset, thisdict.values())).items():
    print(f'{list(combination)} = {count}')
```

This outputs:

```
['Vanilla', 'Chocolate'] = 2
['Vanilla'] = 1
['Chocolate'] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

How about first generating sorted copies of all the lists in the dict, then converting each to tuple, then hashing each tuple? This should deal with duplicated values perhaps better than a set:

```
test =[tuple(sorted(x)) for x in thisdict.values()]
```

make an equivalently ordered hash table for lookup:

```
mytable = [hash(x) for x in test])
```

Then run a loop over it:

```
result = []
for item in test:
    count = 0
    for i, value in enumerate(mytable):
        if hash(item) == value and count == 0:
            count += 1
            result.append([item, count])
        elif hash(item) == value and count >= 1:
            result[:1][0][1] += 1
            test[i] = '(None)'
        else:
            pass
```

Gives:

```
[[('Chocolate', 'Vanilla'), 2], [('Vanilla',), 1], [('Chocolate',), 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI - your dict is improperly formatted, but once properly formatted you can also do this in a relatively straightforward way with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'vals':[*thisdict.values()],'keys':[*thisdict.keys()]})

df

                   vals keys
0  [Vanilla, Chocolate]    1
1             [Vanilla]    2
2           [Chocolate]    7
3  [Chocolate, Vanilla]    8

out = df['vals'].apply(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x))).value_counts()

out

(Chocolate, Vanilla)    2
(Chocolate,)            1
(Vanilla,)              1
Name: vals, dtype: int64
```